# Can I generate i18n JSON files for Svelte app using Rollup?

Tags: json, webpack, internationalization, rollup, svelte

I have a Svelte Rollup JS app. I have implemented my own i18n. I have `en-us/[function].json` and `de-de/[function].json`. I `fetch` the `JSON` at runtime and display the text.

*en-us/login.json*

```js
{
  "username": {
    "label": "Username"
  }
}
```

*de-de/login.json*

```js
{
  "username": {
    "label": "Nutzername"
  }
}
```

Functions like login and sign up have common texts. In the above example, the `username` field is used in both the screens/functions. If I have to make a change to the text, I will have to change all the `[function].json` files in all language folders. In this case, if I change the `username.label`, I will have to change in 4 files `en-us/login.json`, `en-us/signup.json`, `de-de/login.json`, `de-de/signup.json`.

Is there a better way to handle it? Can I generate these JSON files using Rollup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a javascript gettext port like [guillaumepotier/gettext.js](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/gettext.js/), or [Jed](https://messageformat.github.io/Jed/). The former suggests to use [xgettext-php](https://github.com/Wisembly/xgettext-php) together with [Poedit](https://poedit.net) to extract/edit the [PO files](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/PO-Files.html). Probably you could use also [jspot](https://github.com/praekeltfoundation/jspot) for the extraction.

See also [po2json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/po2json).

Here it is [an article](http://www.jeromesteunou.net/internationalisation-in-javascript.html) explaining the process with Jed and jspot.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I don't need a library to load and display my JSON files. And using .PO files with libraries to extract and generate the JSON sounds like an overkill. However, the popularity of PO files amongst the translating community is an upsell for it. I will keep in mind. Looking forward to more ideas from others.

Comment: @Ravi since you asked if you can generate those JSON files from Rollup, unless you roll out your own solution, the only way I can see is by adopting a "standard" like gettext and using something existing like jspot + po2json (or xgettext-php) for the extraction of the JSON files.